# Access range of specific elements of std_logic_vector in one clock

Tags: vhdl

I want to access specific elements of a vector and add their values in one single clock. The cache inputs have been written prior to this calc, so they can be accessed immediately.

```
type cache_type is array (89 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);
signal input_cache : cache_type := (others => (others => '0'));

signal cluster_square_sum   : integer   := 0;

calc: process (clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) and cache_ready then
     cluster_square_sum  <= conv_integer(input_cache(5)) + 
         conv_integer(input_cache(6)) + conv_integer(input_cache(7)) + 
         conv_integer(input_cache(12)) + conv_integer(input_cache(13)) + 
         conv_integer(input_cache(14)) + conv_integer(input_cache(15)) + ...
  end if;
end process;
```

How can I implement this behavior without writing all desired elements explicitly in the addition? I've thought about a variable iterator in the process, but it would not work because of the single clock computation.

Actually, I don't need a process in the first place, I could write my summation directly in the architecture with a "when statement"

```
cluster_square_sum  <= conv_integer(input_cache(5)) + 
         conv_integer(input_cache(6)) + conv_integer(input_cache(7)) + 
         conv_integer(input_cache(12)) + conv_integer(input_cache(13)) + 
         conv_integer(input_cache(14)) + conv_integer(input_cache(15)) + ...
         when cache_ready <= '1';
```

Unfortunately, I don't know a way in implementing my behavior in one of the ways.

Comment: `conv_integer` means you are using `std_logic_arith`. Do not use this package, instead `use ieee.numeric_std.all`, and give your signals numeric types like `signed`. This will eliminate ugly type conversions.

Comment: You seem to want to implement a single-cycle 90?-input adder. This will take a lot of area and perform poorly if you are targeting a real hardware device. I suggest you look at accumulating the values one by one instead.

Comment: Ok, good point, but could be a way of doing this? @scary_jeff

Answer (score 2):

Several things about your question are unclear, but one thing about the question is clear : better design would let you use the type system instead of fighting it every line.

One thing that's unclear : what are you storing in the cache? Is it exclusively reserved for numbers, or is this a CPU cache which can store numbers, text, instructions etc?

If it's exclusively for numeric data then

```
type cache_type is array (89 downto 0) of natural range  0 to 2**14 - 1;
```

will simplify your sum a lot. Or the equivalent signed integer range, whichever is appropriate for your application. This also makes the design intent clear. Or you can use `signed` or `unsigned` from `numeric_std`.

```
cluster_square_sum  <= input_cache(5) + input_cache(6) + input_cache(7) + ...
         when cache_ready <= '1';
```

It's also unclear what subset of cache you are summing over, especially since this isn't an [MCVE] and appears to cover a non-contiguous range. So I'll just have to guess it's a fixed continuous subset; you could employ a loop.

```
calc: process (clk)
variable running_total : natural;
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
     if cache_ready then
        running_total := 0;
        for i in lower_bound to upper_bound loop
           running_total := running_total + input_cache(6)(i);
        end loop;
        cluster_square_sum  <= running_total;
     end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

The variable allows instant assignment (variable assignment semantics) rather than postponed assignment (signal assignment semantics) so you get a running total.

If the bounds aren't constant (or generics), or the range isn't contiguous, this strategy needs some modification.

Another unclear thing is your speed (latency and throughput) and logic size goals. This will perform every addition in a single cycle, but that cycle is likely to be rather slow. If you potentially need an output every clock cycle, with a realistic clock rate, you'll have to pipeline it.

Or if you have plenty of cycles after `cache_ready` before you need an output, embed the loop and computation in a state machine triggered by `cache_ready`. This can perform one addition (and loop iteration) per clock cycle, allowing `input_cache` to be a Block Ram rather than individually accessible registers, for a very small and fast-clocked design. (And in that case, with only one addition per clock, you can safely use either a variable or a signal for `running_total`.

Answer (score 1):

In all cases, I would suggest to use a function.

There doesn't seem to be any logic in the elements you want to add, so I made the functions accept a set of element indices.

"Minimal" example:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity e is
    port(clk: in std_logic);
end entity;

architecture a of e is
    use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

    type cache_type is array(0 to 89) of std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);
    signal input_cache : cache_type := (
        5 => "000010101010101",
        6 => "000001010101010",
        7 => "000000101010101",
        12 => "000000010101010",
        13 => "000000001010101",
        14 => "000000000101010",
        15 => "000000000010101",
        others => (others => '0'));

    type integer_array is array(natural range <>) of integer;
    constant elements_to_add : integer_array := (5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15);

    signal cluster_square_sum   : integer   := 0;

    function add_elements(input_array : cache_type; element_idxs: integer_array) return integer is
        variable output : integer := 0;
    begin
        for idx in element_idxs'low to element_idxs'high loop
            output := output + to_integer(unsigned(input_array(element_idxs(idx))));
        end loop;
        return output;
    end;

begin
    calc: process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            cluster_square_sum  <= add_elements(input_cache, elements_to_add);
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Note that you could also do the process-less/direct assignment with this function.

Plus testbench:

```
entity e_tb is end entity;

library IEEE;

architecture a of e_tb is
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
begin
    UUT : entity work.e port map (clk => clk);

    test: process begin
        wait for 1 ns;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for 1 ns;
        clk <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Please note that it if you want to implement this in an FPGA, you will require quite some resources and lose performance. It would then be better to pipeline your design: use multiple clock cycles to add the elements.